# Error en Autocomplete de buscador

Tags: laravel, autocompletar

Tengo un buscador al que me gustaría implementar un Auto completado pero no me funciona correctamente si compruebo la variable tiene los datos sin embargo no me los muestra en el buscador ??

**Controlador**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('search');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function autocomplete(Request $request)
    {
      $data = Product::select("nombre")
      ->where("nombre","LIKE","%{$request->input('query')}%")
      ->get();

        return response()->json($data);
    }
}
```

**Blade**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel 5.7 Autocomplete Search using Bootstrap Typeahead JS - ItSolutionStuff.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.1/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Laravel 5.7 Autocomplete Search using Bootstrap Typeahead JS - ItSolutionStuff.com</h1>
    <input class="typeahead form-control" type="text" id="typeahead">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "{{ route('autocomplete') }}";
    $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get(path, { query: query }, function (data) {
                return process(data);
            });
        }
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('search', 'SearchController@index')->name('search');

Route::get('autocomplete', 'SearchController@autocomplete')->name('autocomplete');
```

Entrando directamente a localhost/autocomplete puedo ver que estan los datos pero en el buscador nada donde puede estar el error ??

Comment: Comprueba que se esté llamando al servidor a la url del `autocomplete` y que la llamada devuelva un código 200 para ver que ha ido bien. Puedes meter líneas de `logging` para comprobar que pasa por cada punto: en la función `autocomplete` puedes usar `\Log::info('loquequieras')` para escribir en el registro de Laravel mientras que en la parte de javascript podrías poner un `console.log(data)` antes del `process(data)`

Comment: he comprobado que envía  el query por método GET correctamente, También comprobé que la ruta autocomplete tiene los datos.  Pero no doy con el fallo..